# How do you print information on PIC18f4520 LCD display in ASSEMBLY

Tags: assembly, pic, lcd

This is the program which is supposed to print the information "Hello" on an LCD-display.

The problem is that as soon as I compile and run program, the LCD-screen doesn't do anything, just stays lit, without information. Might there be something wrong with delays?

I've tried changing the delays without any change, and I'm pretty sure cables and such are connected correctly since I have two chips running with the same cabling etc.

```
   #include "p18F4520.inc"

    CONFIG  OSC = HS
    CONFIG  PWRT = OFF
    CONFIG  WDT = OFF
    CONFIG  PBADEN = OFF
    CONFIG  LVP = OFF

    org 0x000000

;80MS**
IDSHORT    equ 0x07D
IDLONG    equ 0x07E
ED80MS    CLRF    IDSHORT
    CLRF    IDLONG
LDLOOP    DECFSZ    IDSHORT
    GOTO    LDLOOP
    DECFSZ    IDLONG
    GOTO    LDLOOP
    RETURN
;80MS**
    CLRF    TRISD
    CLRF    TRISB
    BCF        PORTB,RB2
    CALL    ED80MS
    CALL    ED80MS
    CALL    ED80MS
    CALL    ED80MS
    MOVLW   UPPER(MYCOM)
    MOVWF   TBLPTRU
    MOVLW   HIGH(MYCOM)
    MOVWF   TBLPTRH
    MOVLW   LOW(MYCOM)
    MOVWF   TBLPTRL
C1  TBLRD+
    MOVF    TABLAT,W    ;Lägg in ovan i WREG
    IORLW   0x0
    BZ    SEND_DAT
    CALL    COMNWRT
    CALL    ED80MS
    BRA    C1
SEND_DAT    MOVLW   UPPER(MYDATA)
    MOVWF   TBLPTRU
    MOVLW   HIGH(MYDATA)
    MOVWF   TBLPTRH
    MOVLW   LOW(MYDATA)
    MOVWF   TBLPTRL
DT1 TBLRD+
    MOVF    TABLAT,W
    IORLW   0x0
    BZ    OVER
    CALL    DATAWRT
    CALL    ED80MS
    BRA    DT1
OVER    BRA OVER
COMNWRT    MOVWF    PORTD ;Skicka till LCD
    BCF    PORTB,RB0
    BCF    PORTB,RB1
    BSF    PORTB,RB2
    CALL    ED80MS
    BCF    PORTB,RB2
    RETURN
DATAWRT ;Skriv data till LCD
    MOVWF    PORTD ;Flytta till LCD
    BSF    PORTB,RB0
    BCF    PORTB,RB1
    BSF    PORTB,RB2
    CALL    ED80MS
    BCF    PORTB,RB2
    RETURN
    ORG    500H
MYDATA    DB "HELLO",0 ;Data och null
MYCOM    DB    0x38,0x0E,0x01,0x06,0x84,0 ;Instruktioner och null
    END
```

Comment: For a PIC18F4520 assembly language program what you posted is wrong in almost every way any program could be wrong.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment edit your post to include the circuit diagram, the complete text of the assignment with the course title and the name of the institution where you are enrolled. Then I will complete the assignment for you and post the answer here.